# Statically linking ICU on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, linker, icu

I am trying to use ICU Unicode in my C++ Project.

I have downloaded the libraries from [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-67-1), and then linked them by:

1. Adding the lib64 directory to Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
2. Adding the names of all the .lib files into the Input tab.

I then #include "ucnv.h", and the build and run.

The program builds fine, but I get this error message saying I need to put the DLL next to the exe.

I do that, and it runs fine. My questions is

**How do I statically link ICU to my project?**

### What I have tried

I have tried downloading the Master from github, and opening the allinone.sln file, and then setting the following:

1. Release and x64
2. Changing the output from DLL to Static Lib
3. Adding U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION to all of the project-preprocessors

I then rebuild, and then add each one of the projects release directories to the Additional Library Directories section of my projects properties, and then also adding the names of the libraries to the Input Section.

Now this actually works for UTF-8, **however**, for another encoding such as Big-5 most of the functions (and basically all essentials) return NULL.

Also, another reason for a static library is because the DLL I downloaded is over 16MB, which is way too big. On ICU docs they even say that they recommend static linking to reduce size (by removing unneeded)

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? Statically linking against a library introduces lots of restrictions, ultimately locking yourself into using a single version of a single compiler. While that problem can be solved in theory, the problem of linking against two or more libraries with incompatible compiler options cannot.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to statically link ICU to my application so I don't have to supply another dll.

Comment: You can solve that problem by adding the DLL as a custom resource as well, and unpacking it as needed. The `/DELAYLOAD` linker option conveniently deals with the situation where a compile-time linked DLL isn't available during process creation.

Comment: @IInspectable Does this affect startup time? When I startup the app, I believe ICU immediately searches for the DLL, as that's why I get the runtime error at startup, even if I don't use ICU at that time.

Comment: Compile-time dynamically linked imports are resolved at process creation time. Delay-load imports are resolved at the time of first use. I believe this also allows you to postpone ICU's startup code until the first use of a library export. That gives you enough time to prepare your application's runtime environment.

Comment: What minimum version of Windows do you want to target? Recent versions of Windows have ICU built-in, so there's no need to carry a DLL or statically link it.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Hi! Thank you for your reply. However, I have figured out what to do already (just build the data and embed it)